# Mapping Firebase element as array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am developing a Pool betting app. Everything looks good and Im finishing the final module on it.

In firebase, I have a POOL of bets, that have many users. Any user has many matches with their betting on the matches. Like this:

[image]

When I do a request on the firebase like this:

```
 fetchPoolData = async () => {
    const { firebaseApp } = this.props;

    await firebaseApp
      .database()
      .ref(`/pools/${this.props.location.state.pool.key}/users`)
      .once("value")
      .then(snapshot => {
        this.setState({
          poolData: this.snapshotToArray(snapshot),
          isLoadingPool: false
        });
      });
  };
```

Everything Looks great. Now I have an array of users, and want to make some calculations to get the points each user did on each match. So Im mapping the users like this:

```
this.props.poolData.map(user => {
  allUserMatches.push(calculatePoints(user.matches, outcomeMatches));
});
```

The issue here is that user.matches IS NOT being retrieved as an array. Instead, its coming like a big json object that I can map and make my math to calculate the points.

[image]

How can I map this element? If I do a Object.keys I only got a object like this:

```
Object.keys(user.matches)
(66) ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "result", "topscorer"
```

And If I do a Object.entries, it is still not very usefull (because I need to do a find on the objects of the array, to get the elements filtered by an atribute of the object).

```
Object.entries(user.matches)
(66) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)
```

Im lost here. What to do?

Comment: This is more about transforming the object with number indices to an array I guess. How would you like the data to look like?

Comment: Like this: 

Array(66)
0
:
{away_result: "1", away_team: 2, date: "2018-06-14T18:00:00+03:00", finished: false, group: "a", …}
1
:
{away_result: "1", away_team: 4, date: "2018-06-15T17:00:00+05:00", finished: false, group: "a", …}
2
:
{away_result: "2", away_team: 6, date: "2018-06-15T21:00:00+03:00", finished: false, group: "b", …}
3
:

Comment: yeah, but how would you like to have it transformed to?

Comment: I want to forget this fancy keys the firebase do to my object. I want a good and old array starting at 0 and ending at 66, with each value of this array being something like "away_result: "1", away_team: 2, date: "2018-06-14T18:00:00+03:00", finished: false"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use such mapping you can go with

```
Object.keys(user.matches).map(key => user.matches[key])
```

Above will return you keys from each object which later on can be used in map of object through their keys.
Also it doesn't return as array as you have two wild properties (result and topscorer) that doesn't work like array indexes so it need to return them as Object instead of an Array

A way to retrieve all values without result and topscorer from that key value pair

```
Object.keys(user.matches).filter(key => Number.isInteger(parseInt(key))).map(key => user.matches[key]).
```

Comment: I didnt get it Siroo. What Im doing here is that my user.matches became a single array like this: :
0: away_result
:
"1"
away_team
:
2
date
:
"2018-06-14T18:00:00+03:00"
finished
:
false
group
:
"a"
home_result
:
"1"
home_team
:
1
key
:
"1"
name
:
1
stadium
:
1
type
:
"group"
__proto__
:
Object
1
:
away_result
:
"1"
away_team
:
4
date
:
"2018-06-15T17:00:00+05:00"

Comment: It is not a problem this two wild properties, because inside this value I have an attribute that can be filtered correctly.

Comment: But you have within that user.matches also two properties which are NOT looking like array indexes ( "result", "topscorer" ) so Firebase returns that as an object field with array indexes as property names and also result and topscorer.

If you want to remove these two fields also you could do something like 

       Object.keys(user.matches).filter(key => Number.isInteger(parseInt(key))).map(key => user.matches[key]).

With above line you will have normal map iteration of array elements with exclusion of result and topscorer

Comment: Also my suggestion is to avoid situation where you want to have an array but by accident you add two proeprties that break that structure so Firebase automatically will conver it to object key value pairs instead of array with indexes. It is easier then to work with data in that way

Comment: Forget about it. The option you told me just works. Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 0):

This will transform the object with number indices (type string) to the array you want:

```
Object.keys(user.matches).reduce((arr, key) => {
  arr[parseInt(key)] = user.matches[key]
  return arr
}, [])
```